# How to find out when the window is resized in python turtle?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I have a function that draws a circle based on the screensize of the window. Currently, if I make the window smaller, the entire circle isn't visible. Is there any way to find out if the window has been resized so I can redraw the circle to fit in the window?

Here's my code to draw the circle:

```py
def draw_circle():
    # Get circle radius
    screensize = s.screensize()
    if screensize[0] > screensize[1]:
        smaller = 1
    else:
        smaller = 0

    radius = screensize[smaller]

    # Draw circle
    t.pensize(15)
    t.pu()
    t.goto(0, -radius)
    t.pd()
    t.circle(radius)
    t.pu()
```

I have tried to add an if statement that checks if the screensize changes in my main loop, but that didn't work either.

P.S. I tried searching Google and StackOverflow and found no answers.

Comment: From what I understand this will not be possible as you draw pixels. You could implement a scaling factor so that you scale your drawing to the canvas. But if you reshape there is no way to rescale already painted parts. You maybe could erase the image and the start all over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to poll in a loop. Once you get the underlying Tkinter canvas with `turtle.getcanvas()`, you can look up the non-turtle Tkinter approach and use that. For example, adapting [Tkinter track window resize specifically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61712329/tkinter-track-window-resize-specifically) to turtle gives the following minimal example:

```py
import turtle

def resize(event):
    print(event.width, event.height)

turtle.getcanvas().bind("<Configure>", resize)
turtle.exitonclick()
```

Note that this doesn't change the screen size, so you can draw your circle relative to the window instead:

```
import turtle

def draw():
    r = min(turtle.window_width(), turtle.window_height()) / 2 - 30
    turtle.clear()
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.goto(0, -r)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.circle(r)
    turtle.end_fill()
    turtle.update()

def resize(event):
    draw()

turtle.tracer(0)
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.getcanvas().bind("<Configure>", resize)
draw()
turtle.exitonclick()
```

Drawing relative sizes for everything tends to be pretty tedious, so I recommend avoiding this if at all possible for your app.